Issue in agora sdk when run in android 14
I am currently working on kotlin project which has AgoraClassSDK and AgoraDUIKit sub module, currently the app is working properly on Android 13, but in 14 I got broadcast receiver error when I tried to solve. Then I found issue in one SDK that SDK is not editable
Agora issue :

java.lang.SecurityException: com.tutortod: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or
RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being
registered exclusively for system broadcasts
android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3071)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3055)
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3038
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2980
atandroid.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6380)
atandroid.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1876)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1811
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1799
at
android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:755)
at io.agora.chat.core.EMAdvanceDebugManager.h(Unknown Source:20
at io.agora.chat.core.EMAdvanceDebugManager.a(Unknown Source:2)
at io.agora.chat.ChatClient.onNewLogin(Unknown Source:38)
at io.agora.chat.ChatClient$8.run(Unknown Source:165)

